# Tracking Phone Position in real world via Android with Radio or other signal

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

I am currently doing research on ways to track a phones position relative to some radio/bluetooth/wifi signals.

I have already developed a small application using the android Wifi manager to scan for access points but this solution is just way too slow, takes roughly 1-2 seconds for the scan to refresh.

I need the latency for the tracking to be quite low, maybe maximum 100 milliseconds.

As far as I understand its not possible to speed up the android wifi manager, so I was wondering if anyone has any experience or knows of a way if possible to scan for radio signals or bluetooth signals from an android device any faster?

I need a really low latency, high precision solution, to say track position of a user inside of a single empty room as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an indoor scenario I would recommend using iBeacons. They are quite cheap, very precise, drain very little battery and work with Android devices also.
There are even multiple free libraries for a better API.
The only drawback is that devices have to support Bluetooth Low Energy.

The more iBeacons you use, the better. The signals will overlap but it is easy to find the closest by considering the signal strength. You can even to things like triangulation for even more precise localization.

Comment: I just had a look at someone using iBeacons to triangulate and it doesnt look like they are too accurate :(. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMWEl6GBGqk

Comment: In the comments they say to use more for accuracy but their 100 dollars 3, it may be doable though thanks!